# How to close a userform when another userform or a blank space is selected in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Whenever people clicks on the `Debit Account` or `Credit Account` fields on the userform, another userform with a `Treeview` will pop-out. However, the user will always have to press cancel in order to close the userform. Is there a way for the userform to automatically close when the `Voucher Entry Form` userform's area is selected?

[image: Sample Userform]

Comment: Do using [Hide Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/hide-method) of the userform which shall be hidden. Or do using [Unload Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/unload-statement) to unload the userform which is not needed further. Better answer is not possible without seeing your code.

Comment: @AxelRichter Before we can use`Hide` or `Unload` what event triggers those? That is the issue for me. Assume 2 userforms with no functionality (just a plain userform) and if you select on the 2nd userform or press on an empty space, the 1st userform will close. That's the thing i'm trying to figure out. What event or code is available to do that--if any

Comment: Where are the buttons `trvCreditAccount` and `trvDebitAccount` located? Ad if it is a user form too, then how are you opening that main user form?

Comment: `trvCreditAccount` and `trvDebitAccount` are labels they just look like textboxes because they are sunken (Special Effect property). Then when I click the labels, the userform activates using `Userform.Show`. The are directly above the userform without the title bar as shown above.

Comment: And how  are you opening that user form where the labels `trvCreditAccount` and `trvDebitAccount` are located?

Comment: The `frmDebitAccount.Show` and `frmCreditAccount.Show` as shown above

Comment: Those commands are opening the subforms. But how are you opening the main form?

Comment: Worksheet activate event with `VoucherEntry.Show` I actually never knew you could add properties to the `.Show` so I doubt i'll have any modes in calling my userforms

Comment: `VoucherEntry.Show vbModeless` then?

Comment: Oh that I didn't do. When I added `vbModeless` it worked. But the main form vanishes everytime I click the label that shows the sub-form

Comment: OK, I am out here now. Cannot reproducing your problem. And this is not the right place developing this for you single step by single step.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the help really appreciate it already got the issue. I have an `Unload Me` at my main form's deactivate event that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "How to unload a user-form if it is not more the active  object?" then the user-form in question must be modeless. Because else it cannot be deactivated without closing it's window. And because it is not possible opening a modeless user-form from a modal userform, the main user-form also must be modeless.

Example:

Do having two user-forms:

First user-form is named "MainForm" and has one button control and the following code applied:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Load SubForm
 SubForm.Show vbModeless
 SubForm.Left = Me.Left + 100
 SubForm.Top = Me.Top + 100
End Sub
```

Second user-form is named "SubForm" and can be empty but has following code applied:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
 Unload Me
End Sub
```

Then following `Sub` within a default module shows the main form:

```
Sub test()
  MainForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Now after MainForm is shown, SubForm can be opened by button click. And if MainForm get the active form again (gets the focus again), the SubForm will unload.

Comment: Thanks I think `vbModeless` is  an important part of the code. Although when `MainForm` is selected, does the `SubForm` close in this code? My goal is making `SubForm` behave like a combobox

Comment: @Marc Santos: "Although when MainForm is selected, does the SubForm close in this code?": What else do you think `Unload` is doing? There is no guarantee though that this works properly together with your approach for making a seamless user form without window border and title bar.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll test it with the userform. I just adapted the seamless user form without window border and title bar

Comment: I get an error stating: `Run-time error 401: Can't show non-modal form when modal form is displayed` due to the `vbModeless`

Comment: @Marc Santos: As said already in my answer, **both** user-forms must be modeless.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's the window-less forms that isn't modeless. It uses some `User32` stuff that I just adapted

Comment: @Marc Santos: No, as the error states, the main form which tries opening the sub form is not modeless. How do you opening the main form?

Comment: Just `Userform.Show`

Comment: Then do using `Userform.Show vbModeless` as shown in my answer?

Comment: It errors when I try to do so with the error shown above.